# Stackview label not adding programmatically

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do everything without a story board but keep getting nil when adding my label but I can't see why. Im sure its dead simple and I'm being blind but I just can't see it after a lot of googling.

View Controller:

```
    class SquaresViewController: UIViewController {

        let stackView = OAStackView()
        let titleView = TitleView(frame: CGRect.zero)

        @IBOutlet var squaresCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            stackView.axis = .vertical
            stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleView)
            titleView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.height.equalTo(50)
                make.top.equalTo(view.snp.top)
                make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left)
                make.right.equalTo(view.snp.right)
            }

        }
    }
```

titleView:

```
    import UIKit

    class TitleView: UIView {

        @IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            createView()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        func createView() {
            titleText = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
            titleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            titleText.text = "Tappy tap tap a square!"
            titleText.textAlignment = .center
            titleText.numberOfLines = 0

            self.addSubview(titleText)

            titleText.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.edges.equalTo( self.snp.edges )
            }
        }
    }
```

When building it fails at:

```
    titleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

with:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why you created an `IBOutlet` for titleText if you don't want to use storyboards. If you don't want to use storyboards, change the implementation to:

```
var titleText : UILabel!
```

Secondly, the application is crashing because you are asking it to perform an operation on a view that is not yet added to the hierarchy. For ease of reading I have commented out all lines except those that are important. See below:

```
func createView() {
    //titleText = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
    titleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // <-- You are trying to perform an operation on titleText here

    //titleText.text = "Tappy tap tap a square!"
    //titleText.textAlignment = .center
    //titleText.numberOfLines = 0

    self.addSubview(titleText) // <-- but you are adding it to the view hierarchy here

    //titleText.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        //make.edges.equalTo( self.snp.edges )
    //}
}
```

`titleText` has to be added to the view hierarchy before you can call `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on it, like so:

```
self.view.addSubview(titleText)
titleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // <-- Here we are waiting until the view has been added to the hierarchy to perform operations on it
```

So try changing implementation to look like so:

```
import UIKit

class TitleView: UIView {

    var titleText: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // leave as is, removed for space
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // leave as is, removed for space
    }

    func createView() {
        titleText = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        titleText.text = "Tappy tap tap a square!"
        titleText.textAlignment = .center
        titleText.numberOfLines = 0

        self.addSubview(titleText)
        titleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        titleText.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo( self.snp.edges )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried reordering everything but the iboutlet was the main issue.

Comment: No problem! @WayneRumble